# How to resolve "Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved."

Tags: xamarin.forms, automapper

I'm using Xamain.Forms 4.8.0.1560. The moment that add AutoMapper to the solution I'm getting the `warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.` (for the Android project)

Following are the NuGet packages that I'm using

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Acr.UserDialogs">
      <Version>7.1.0.462</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper">
      <Version>10.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity.Forms">
      <Version>7.2.0.1422</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.8.0.1560" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.5.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

How can I resolve this warning?

Comment: I create new blank Xamaron.Forms project, version 4.8.0.1560, then installing the AutoMapper  for this solution, but I can not get any error, so can you create new project and try it again.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I got the warning in a new project. I was getting the warning in my projects so I tried to investigate by creating a new project and add the NuGet Packages that I was using.

Comment: add tis to the android app: **<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />**

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm still getting the warning after adding the `PackageReference` that you proposed

Comment: @Dimitris I think if your project can works fine and you can use AutoMapper correctly, you can leave it alone.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I know that the projects are working fine. I'm getting this warning for a long long time. I'm just curious for the reason that is happening and how to make it go away, as well as solving similar situations

Comment: add AutoGenerateBindingRedirects with true setting to csproj

Comment: @magicandre1981 Didn't work. Still getting the warning!

Comment: in this case simply don't use automapper. Move this code into a middleware and use HTTP services to communicate to the app to send/request data from the middleware

Comment: @magicandre1981Thanks for the suggestion. It's not about using or not the AutoMapper. Apps are working OK despite the warning. It's about finding out why this warning appears and how to fix it. It bothers me that I don't know why this warning appears and that I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: assembly bindings is a strange topic. In obj folders there is a project.assets.json file for your android app, look for Microsoft.CSharp entries where they come from. maybe you see which other lib has a Microsoft.CSharp reference

Comment: @Dimitris If you don't use any Microsoft products i.e. you exclude Microsoft/Visual Studio et. al. completely from you life as a developer ... then the error FINALLY goes away!